# check a "#N/A" value in vba into a range

Tags: vba, error-handling, excel

I want to check a `#N/A` value into excel with VBA. So after some research, I made this code :

```
Set MyTab = Range(name)
If (Not IsEmpty(MyTab.value)) And (MyTab(i, j).value <> CVErr(xlErrNA)) Then
   Call BuildRequest(False, id, MyTab, i, j)
End If
```

But when it passed on `MyTab(i, j).value <> CVErr(xlErrNA)` I have an error `13(type error)` and I don't find why.

Anyone can help me plz ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You first need to check that the cell does contain an error:

```
If IsError(MyTab(i, j).Value) Then
    If MyTab(i, j).Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
```

Unless you do want to know the type of error (#N/A, #DIV/0!, etc) , you might as well replace your test with:

```
If (Not IsEmpty(MyTab.value)) And (Not IsError(MyTab(i, j).value)) Then
```

If you need to check the error type, you can write:

```
Dim shouldBuildRequest As Boolean

shouldBuildRequest = Not IsEmpty(MyTab.value)
If IsError(MyTab(i, j).Value) Then
    shouldBuildRequest = shouldBuildRequest AND (MyTab(i, j).Value <> CVErr(xlErrNA))
End If

If shouldBuildRequest Then
    Call BuildRequest(False, id, MyTab, i, j)
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for it :). You to Siddharth Rout

Answer (score 7):

Another way to check for the error

```
If CVErr(MyTab(i, j).Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA)
```

Comment: I am trying to do a similar error check for a merged cells ("B6:D6"), I am using the below code and come up with error.   If CVErr(ws.Range("B6").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then