# VBA not exiting function on error

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-2007, vba

Using the code below, I am trying to extrapolate the column letter of to the right of a column where a defined value exists. For example, if D1 = 'Postcode', I want `insert_col` to equal 'E'.

This works if the value 'Postcoade' exists in `title_range`, but if it does not I get an error on the last line (Type mismatch).

According to the docs for Match, if the lookup value does not exist in the reange, the Excel error "N/A" is returned, but checking for `xlErrNA` to exit the function does not work.

```
' Work out the column to insert
insert_col_pos = Application.Match("Postcode", title_range, 0)
If insert_col_pos = xlErrNA Then Exit Function ' Exit if the column to insert next to does not exist
insert_col = GetInsertCol(insert_col_pos + 1)
```

Does any body know what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394029/check-a-n-a-value-in-vba-into-a-range

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the `If IsError() Then` check helped me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
If insert_col_pos = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then Exit Sub
```

Provided that `insert_col_pos` is `Dim`'ed as `Variant`

Comment: Well, that works if there is an error genereated, but now does not if there is no error generated (type mismatch again). `insert_col_pos` is indeed a `Variant`, so presumably this error is now being caused because when the value I'm looking for is found, it is infact a `String`?

Comment: Never mind, I've added an `If IsError() Then` check, and I've got it working. Thanks for your help.