# How can I check if a Multi-Cell Range contains any errors?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use VBA to check if a Range in Excel contains any #N/A or other types of errors?  I know how to do it for a single cell:

`IsError(Sheets("Main").Range("B1").value`

but doing the same for a multi-cell range:

`IsError(Sheets("Main").Range("A12:N32").value)`

does not pick up an error.  If I use the IsError function as a formula in one of the cells of the sheet, it works and picks up the error:

`=ISERROR(A12:N32)`

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try this `Set Rng = Sheets("Main").Range("A12:N32").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)`

Comment: @Santosh If there are no Errors in the range, this command returns an error and the code stops running!

Comment: You can use error handling. Refer this [link](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/Lesson26.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please open a **new workbook** and try the code below. 
This will write 3 values to column A, then iterate through the column and show a msgbox if an error occurs. Try it!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Throw_Errors()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i&: Set ws = Sheets(1)
    ws.Range("A2") = "=100/0"
    ws.Range("A3") = "=A2/0"
    ws.Range("A4") = "=100/10"
    For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = ws.Range("A" & i)
        If IsError(rng) Then MsgBox "error in row" & rng.Row
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394029/check-a-n-a-value-in-vba-into-a-range) if you want to learn how to check for different types of errors!