# Excel VBA - Search Another Sheet On Cell Click

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a way to get excel to search Sheet2 for the same text in the cell that was clicked on Sheet1.

For example:
Sheet2 contains names (column A), addresses (column B), and cities (column c), while Sheet1 holds a list of the same names (along with various other info). For simplicity's sake, all I need is to be able to click a name on Sheet1 and have it return the row number of the same name on Sheet2. Displaying the information in a  message box would work well enough.

Any ideas on how I might be able to get this to work? I'm having trouble finding where to get started.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it. If you don't know where to start, try using the Macro Recorder.

Comment: You can use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event for this

Comment: That is my problem, for this function I have nothing other that the knowledge of placing it in Worsheet_SelectionChange event. I am not a coder and thought this could be a place for some guidance.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I posted the code for you. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in Sheet1 (Sheet1):

[image: Sheet1]

Assuming the names of your sheets are Sheet1 and Sheet2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'If you select more than one cell, ignore
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

'If you select a blank cell, ignore
If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Dim Finder, ClickRange

'We want the event to fire if you click in column A anywhere
Set ClickRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

'If you click somewhere else, ignore
If Intersect(Target, ClickRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Look for the value in sheet 2 column A
Set Finder = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

'If we don't find it, Exit Sub
If Finder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'To display the row:
MsgBox (Finder.Row)

'To Select it:
'If we find it, select sheet 2 and select the cell
'Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Finder.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `Find()` doesn't trigger an error if the value isn't found, so you don't need the `On Error Resume Next` here

Comment: Thanks, updated. I feel like I have seen Find throw an error before when setting the value, but it didn't in the example I tested. The line `If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub` does throw an error if the cell value is an error (Like `#N/A`) which is kind of annoying.

Comment: `if len(trim(Target.Value)) = 0 then`

Comment: I still get a type mismatch error when using that Siddharth. You can just wrap it in error handlers, but that's the reason I wrapped find in error handlers - never know when excel is going to throw an error on an arbitrary line -___-

Comment: Sorry. I was just updating that. You will have use `CVerr()` to check that. See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394029/check-a-n-a-value-in-vba-into-a-range)

Comment: @user1274820, you are a rock star! Thank you. Your code works perfectly.

Comment: Np Jeremy, glad to help. Thanks Siddharth. I will check that out. There's always more to learn :)

Comment: You may also want [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211091(v=office.12).aspx) in case you want to trap other kind of errors as well ;)