# Type mismatch when checking for a formula error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple vba code to change some values on column Y and Z. The code is as below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeVALUE()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Const startrow As Byte = 2

LastRow = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = startrow To LastRow

If Range("Y" & i).Value = "N/A" Then
    Range("Y" & i).Value = "F"
End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code is working fine for column Y but the moment I change all range Y to range Z, it will return an error with type mismatch. I keep thinking but can't seem to find the cause. Can anyone help me? I am not sure why it is giving me this error.

Comment: Looks like you have a formula error somewhere. Check the cells in column visually. You may also want to refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394029/check-a-n-a-value-in-vba-into-a-range)

Comment: Which Excel version do you have? And at what point does the execution stop?

Comment: turns out I have #VALUE! in one of the cells. Using isError fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Closing this as a duplicate then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to check if the cell evaluates to an error at all (using `IsError()`) and then you can check the error type.

Just checking if the cell holds the value "N/A" does not work, you need check for the error number using `CVErr(xlErrNA)`.

You may try this modified code:

```
Sub removeVALUE()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Const startrow As Byte = 2
    
    LastRow = Range("Y" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = startrow To LastRow
        
        'Check if the cell evaluates to an error
        If IsError(Range("Y" & i).Value) Then
            'Check the error type (xlErrNA for N/A error
            If Range("Y" & i).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then
                Range("Y" & i).Value = "F"
            End If
        End If
    
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you want to check for different kinds of errors, you may use the following constants instead of `xlErrNa` (taken from [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/cell-error-values)):

```
Constant    Error number    Cell error value
xlErrDiv0   2007            #DIV/0!
xlErrNA     2042            #N/A
xlErrName   2029            #NAME?
xlErrNull   2000            #NULL!
xlErrNum    2036            #NUM!
xlErrRef    2023            #REF!
xlErrValue  2015            #VALUE!
```

Comment: Thanks! turns out I have a #VALUE! in one of the cells

Comment: @user99 I have updated my answer with the right constants for other error types.

Answer (score 1):

### Check for Error Values First

- Nothing to gain from declaring as `Byte`. Better use `Long` for all whole numbers.
- If `N/A` is text, then this will work. If it is `#N/A` instead, use Michael Wycisk's solution.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeVALUE()

    Const StartRow As Long = 2
    Const CritCol As String = "Y"
    Const CritVal As String = "N/A"
    Const NewVal As String = "F"
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range(CritCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim Current As Variant, i As Long
    
    For i = StartRow To LastRow
        Current = Range(CritCol & i).Value
        If Not IsError(Current) Then
            If Current = CritVal Then
                Range(CritCol & i).Value = NewVal
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```